# How to select $(this) and .class to do something in one line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is a silly question but how can I toggleClass() in a single line to both selectors.

```
$('.search-ico').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
        $('.class').toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

I tried below:

```
$('.search-ico').click(function(){
    $(this,'.class').toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

but it's not working (only `this` is taking the class).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `.add` method to combine string selectors and this.
https://api.jquery.com/add/

Use it like this:

```
$(this).add('.class').toggleClass(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the elements of class `search-ico` carry an `id` attribute, you can compose the selector string:

```
$("#" + $(this).attr('id') + ", .class").toggleClass("is-active")
```

Answer (score -1):

note you can also add properties to the first object before adding a second object to it, and whatever property you add after the second object applies to all of them..

```
$(this).css('property','value').add('.class').toggleClass(...)
```

so here the css property of (this) is altered first.. before added to the second object, and then the toggleClass applied to all of them..